# php array_udiff function with strpos

Tags: php

I am using this piece of code for comparing two arrays.

```
<?php
function myfunction($v1,$v2){
    if ($v1===$v2){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

$a1 = array("a"=>"Cat", "b"=>"Dog", "c"=>"Horse");
$a2 = array(1=>"Cat", 2=>"Dog", 3=>"Fish");

print_r(array_udiff($a1,$a2,"myfunction"));
?>
```

The function works well for these arrays.  but i want to use php strpos function instead of `===` operator to compare two values i.e `if(strpos($v1,$v2) === true)`. I tried this but not working. Any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strpos` is for strings, not arrays. What variables are you passing to `myfunction`?

Comment: @crowjonah: `myfunction` is being called via `array_udiff`.

Comment: [`strpos`](http://us3.php.net/strpos) *never* returns `TRUE`.  It returns an int of the index in the string, or `FALSE` if it's not found.

Answer (score 2):

You can try (Note am using `stripos` instead to find case-insensitive substring in a string)

```
function myfunction($v1, $v2) {
    if (stripos($v1, $v2) !== false) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

$a1 = array("a" => "Cat","b" => "Dog","c" => "Horse");
$a2 = array(1 => "Cat",2 => "Dog",3 => "Fish");

print_r(array_udiff($a1, $a2, "myfunction"));
```

Output

```
 Array ( [c] => Horse )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using cake 1.3. You could use diff ( http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Utility-Libraries/Set.html#diff ) It's a Core Utility and very handy. There are other array functions on that manual page as well.

```
$result = Set::diff($a1, $a2);
print_r($result);
```